# How to specify an Include inside a lambda expression

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I have A Rack model and a Server Model. Currently when I want to retrieve single Server I do the following, to specify explicit loading:-

```
public Server FindAllServer(int id)
        {

            return project.Servers.Where(c => c.ServerID == id)
                .Include(a => a.OperatingSystem)
                .Include(a2 => a2.DataCenter)
                .Include(a3=>a3.Rack)
                .Include(a4=>a4.ServerModel)
                .Include(a5=>a5.Technology)
                .Include(a6=>a6.VirtualMachines)
                .Include(a7=>a7.TechnologyStatu)
                .Include(a8=>a8.TechnologyBackUpStatu)
                .Include(a9=>a9.TechnologyRole)
                .SingleOrDefault();
        }
```

But now I want to display a Rack and all its server/s,I did the following :-

```
 public Rack FindAllRack(int id)
        {

            return project.Racks.Where(c => c.RackID == id)
                .Include(a => a.Servers)
                .Include(a2 => a2.DataCenter)
                .Include(a3 => a3.Firewalls)
                .Include(a4 => a4.Routers)
                .Include(a5 => a5.Technology)
                .Include(a6 => a6.StorageDevices)
                .Include(a7=>a7.Switches)
                .Include(a8=>a8.Zone)
                .SingleOrDefault();
        }
```

so I am not sure how I can define to explicitly include all the navigation properties for the Server/s under a Rack, as I cannot write something such as:-

```
project.Racks.Where(c => c.RackID == id).Include(a => a.Servers.Include(………))
```

The problem is that in case I have 50 servers under a rack, then for each server there will be around 7 requests to retrieve the server navigation properties, so I will have around 350 requests !!!

Comment: If you have that may child collections for your parent object, you may want to profile your SQL to make sure your database will hold up under load with production level volumes. I've seen this kind of query work fine in dev and then grid to a halt in production. Are you sure you really need all of the child records?

Comment: yes i need all the child records.

Comment: I am including all these child records, As on the main Rack page i will show how many servers,switches,etc are associated with this Rack. so if i do not include these navigation properties, it will cause a problem as separate requests to retrieve the count of each  navigation property will be sent.

Comment: If you are only showing the count, don't pull back the entire object, just the count for each child set in a flattened representation. It will be much faster.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
return project.Servers
              .Include(a => a.OperatingSystem)
              .Include(a2 => a2.DataCenter)
              .Include(a3=>a3.Rack)
              .Include(a4=>a4.ServerModel)
              .Include(a5=>a5.Technology)
              .Include(a6=>a6.VirtualMachines)
              .Include(a7=>a7.TechnologyStatu)
              .Include(a8=>a8.TechnologyBackUpStatu)
              .Include(a9=>a9.TechnologyRole)
              .Where(srv => srv.Rack.RackID == id);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be able to do this with the string-based overload of `Include()` by specifying a property path, e.g.

```
project.Racks.Where(c => c.RackID == id).Include("Servers.SomePropertyOfServer")
```

**EDIT**: After doing some more research, it appears this may also work:

`project.Racks.Where(c => c.RackID == id).Include(a => a.Servers.Select(s => s.SomePropertyOfServer))`

See [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx), specifically the section entitled "Eagerly Loading Multiple Levels" for an example.

Comment: so in this way i need to re-write the whole include list for the server, inside the include list of the Rack.

Comment: It appears so. You could also project the properties you want into an anonymous type.

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is the count of the various child objects, consider the following instead. It should issue a single request to the database only fetching up to 2 rows. Profile the request to make sure this is the case as I haven't tested it.

```
        return project.Racks.Where(c => c.RackID == id)
            .Select(a => new {
                serverCount = a.Servers.Count(),
                dataCenterCount = a.DataCenter.Count(),
                firewallCount = a.Firewalls.Count(),
                routerCount = a.Routers.Count(),
                technologyCount = a.Technology.Count(),
                storageDeviceCount = a.StorageDevices.Count(),
                switchCount = a.Switches.Count(),
                zoneCount = a.Zone.Count()
            }).SingleOrDefault();
```

Also, if you aren't planning on throwning an exception if you get more than one record, use FirstOrDefault instead of SingleOrDefault.